# Splitting a string into substrings using C

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory, split

I'm trying to make a program that splits the string based on a specific character.

Data Structure used:

```
typedef struct pieces {
    char **members;
    size_t len;
} pieces;
```

Function declarations:

```c
pieces split     (const char *s, const char c);
size_t charCount (const char *s, const char c);
char *slice      (const char *s, int a, int b);
size_t indexOf   (const char *s, const char c, size_t start);
```

`charCount` -> No. of times the char appeared in string.

`indexOf` -> Returns the index of a first occurrence of the given character inside the string, starting from the index `start`; i.e. `indexOf("Stack Overflow", 'O', 0) == indexOf("Stack Overflow", 'O', 3)`

I've implemented `slice` like this:

```c
char *slice  (const char *s, int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b || a == b)  
        return NULL;

    if (b > strlen(s))      // Only slice upto end if tried to slice out of index
        b = strlen(s);      

    size_t len = b - a + 1;
    char *slice = malloc(sizeof(char) * len);

    for (size_t i = a; i < b; i++)
        slice[i - a] = s[i];
    slice[len - 1] = '\0';

    return slice;
}
```

I'm confused on `split` function:

```c
pieces split (const char *s, const char c)
{
    // Is this the right way to make room for incoming slices ?
    pieces arr;
    arr.len = charCount(s, c) + 1;
    arr.members = malloc(sizeof(char *) * arr.len);

    // Should I do something like this to insert slices ?
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(s);)
    {
        int seperator_idx = indexOf(s, c, i);
        char *piece = slice(s, i, seperator_idx);

        arr.members[i] = piece;     // Should I use strdup ??

        i = seperator_idx + 1;
    }

    // What about the last slice ?

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why is there used equality indexOf("Stack Overflow", 'O', 0) == indexOf("Stack Overflow", 'O', 3)?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I guess to show that it will always return an index in the original array...

Comment: I suggest instead of the contrived math inside `slice` you will have a `size_t len` that is the *actual number of characters excluding the terminator, then loop from `0` to one less than that value. Your slice has so much arithmetic it is hard to see if it is right or not.

And no you shouldn't use `strdup` since `slice` already returns a new string, what good would `strdup` then do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72885616/16835308

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues with the proposed prototypes:

- `pieces split(const char *s, const char c);`
  it is unclear if consecutive occurrences of `c` represent empty substrings or a single separator (as in `strtok`). Let's assume empty substrings should be accepted. `const` qualifying `c` is overkill and not meaningless in a prototype
- `size_t charCount(const char *s, const char c);` same remark about `const char c`. Let's assume the null terminator is not part of the string so `charCount("abc", '\0')` is zero.
- `char *slice(const char *s, int a, int b);` why are `a` and `b` typed `int` instead of `size_t`?
- `size_t indexOf(const char *s, const char c, size_t start);` what should this function return in case `c` is not found the string starting from index `start`? Let's assume the offset of the end of string should be returned, as it is more convenient to implement `slice`.

With these conventions, `indexOf` and `charCount` can be written as:

```
#include <stddef.h>

size_t indexOf(const char *s, const char c, size_t start) {
    while (s[start] && s[start] != c)
        start++;
    return start;
}

size_t charCount(const char *s, const char c) {
    size_t count = 0;
    while (*s) {
        count += (*s++ == c);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Your `slice` function has multiple problems:

- It should return an empty string if `a == b`,
- it is confusing to name `len` something that is **not** the length of the substring. Either define `len` as `size_t len = b - a;` or use `size_t size = b - a + 1;`
- it has undefined behavior if `a` is larger than `strlen(s)` and `b > a`.
- you should gracefully return `NULL` in case of `malloc()` failure

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

/* return an empty string if a >= b */
char *slice(const char *s, size_t a, size_t b) {
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    if (a > len)
        a = len;
    if (b < a)
        b = a;
    char *slice = malloc(b - a + 1);
    if (slice != NULL) {
        for (size_t i = a; i < b; i++)
             slice[i - a] = s[i];
        slice[b - a] = '\0';
    }
    return slice;
}
```

The `split` function also has problems:

- naming the `pieces` structure `arr` is confusing: it is not an array.
- your allocation for `arr.members` is correct, but you should test if was allocated successful.
- there is no need to `strdup()` the return value of `slice`, which was allocated with `malloc()`.
- you should use 2 separate index variables for the index `i` into the array `arr.members` and the index of the start of the substring.
- the loop should be written with a test so `split("", c)` return a single empty string.
- if `indexOf` returns the end of the string if `c` cannot be found, no special case is needed for the last slice.

Here is a modified version:

```
pieces split(const char *s, const char c) {
    pieces arr;
    arr.len = charCount(s, c) + 1;
    arr.members = malloc(sizeof(*arr.members) * arr.len);
    if (arr.members != NULL) {
        for (size_t i = 0, start = 0; i < arr.len; i++) {
            size_t end = indexOf(s, c, start);
            arr.members[i] = slice(s, start, end);        
            start = end + 1;
            if (arr.members[i] == NULL) {
                /* free previous substrings and the members array */
                while (i-- > 0) {
                    free(arr.members[i]);
                }
                free(arr.members);
                arr.members = NULL;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Note these final remarks:

- `split` as coded above works too if `indexOf()` returns `(size_t)(-1)` when the character is not found in the string.
- recomputing the length of the string in `slice()` is wasteful. `slice()` should assume that the argument values are correct: `0` <= `a` < `b` <= `strlen(s)`.
- there is no direct way for `split` to return an error. Setting the `members` to `NULL` seems a workable solution.
- instead of `slice()`, and assuming `indexOf` returns a valid offset into the string, you could use the POSIX standard function `strndup()`:

  ```
  arr.members[i] = strndup(s + start, end - start);
  ```

Comment: new to c. I found that split function, you need `for (size_t i = 0,` also you also need to declare the start as size_t?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/eaMY5qz9o  I am sorry to bother  you. If I understand correctly. pieces p1 = split("hello world", 'o');  accessed "hello world" string 3 times. but can only get the first part of substring.

Comment: There was a small mistake in the `slice` function: `slice[b - a] = '\0';` must be placed after the `for` body. I changed the `main` function in https://godbolt.org/z/qcz3hfcEr  and the output is `len=3, { "hell", " w", "rld", }` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To split a string on 1 character, I would do something like:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int count_words(char const *str, char const delim)
{
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (; str[i]; i++) {
        // the next character is the beggining of a new string
        if (str[i] == delim && str[i + 1] != delim)
            count++;
    }
    // for safety
    if (str[i - 1] != delim)
        count++;

    return count;
}

int word_length(char const *str, char const delim)
{
    int length = 0;

    // while we're on a valid character, increase the word length
    while (str[length] && str[length] != delim)
        length++;

    return length;
}

pieces split(char const *str, char const delim)
{
    // move the pointer until we're not on the delimiter
    while (*str == delim)
        str++;

    // prepare the string array
    pieces p;
    p.len = count_words(str, delim);
    p.members = malloc(p.len * sizeof(char *));

    // for each string
    for (int i = 0; i < p.len; i++) {

        // copy the string
        int length = word_length(str, delim);
        p.members[i] = strndup(str, length);

        // move the pointer until we're not on the delimiter
        str += length;
        while (*str == delim)
            str++;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Why do you not consider empty substrings?